# Stripe api is not for everybody?

Tags: python, stripe-payments, shopify, e-commerce, payment

I am a Developer and i want to implement the Stripe payment gateway in my web application but to activate my account they need me to give them information like : where I live.
I live in Morocco and my country isn't included in the list. does this mean I can't use Stripe ?

I just want to know if there any solution for those who don't exist in their country list.

Ps: I don't want to create a fake company and put its address.

Comment: This seems like a question for stripe customer support, not for SO.

Answer (score 2):

If your country is not available in the list, unfortunately you won't be able to use Stripe's services. However, you can sign up to be notified when it's available [here](https://stripe.com/global#signup-form)